# Giving height 100% to parent div to achieve full height border-right disturbs the page layout

Tags: css

I want to achieve full height border-right on child columns. By giving 100% height to new-parent div, I achieve that but that creates a issue that is shown in 2nd image

[image]
[image]

```
body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.new-parent{
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
    max-width: 1080px;

}

.new-col-child{
    height:100%;
    width: 300px;
    display:inline-table;
    margin-left:-3px;
    border-right: 1px solid #E4E2E4;
}

<div class="new-parent">
     <div class="new-col-child"> ..... </div>
     <div class="new-col-child"> ..... </div>
     <div class="new-col-child"> ..... </div>
     <div class="new-col-child"> ..... </div>
     <div class="new-col-child"> ..... </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any images.

Comment: now check , images are available

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have to use box-sizing property, try this:

```
.new-col-child{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:100%;
    width: 300px;
    display:inline-table;
    margin-left:-3px;
    border-right: 1px solid #E4E2E4;
}
```